# MYSQL Dump unexpected rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a mysql dump of a few rows in my database. I can then use the dump to upload those few rows into another database.

```
mysqldump --opt --user=username --password=password lmhprogram myResumes  --where="date_pulled='2011-05-23'" > test.sql
```

**But I've an error: unexpected "date_pulled"**

But I have a column "date_pulled" on my database !

**EDIT:**
If I try mysqldump on the command-prompt it works like this:

```
C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin/mysqldump.exe --host=".$host." --user=".$username." --password=".$password." --where="date_pulled > '2011-05-23'" ".$db." ".$table." > ".$rep_local.$file."
```

Now, If I put this command in `exec()` script in PHP, like:

```
exec("C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin/mysqldump.exe --host=".$host." --user=".$username." --password=".$password." --where="date_pulled > '2011-05-23'" ".$db." ".$table." > ".$rep_local.$file." ");
```

then I have get error: "unexpected date_pulled".

Comment: Maybe show us the code and / or the tables.

Comment: look correct based on the docs - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where

Answer (score 0):

I think the `--where` option needs to appear BEFORE the database name and table name. (That's the way we do it. With the database name and table name at the end of the command.)

```
mysqldump --opt --user=username --password=password --where="date_pulled='2011-05-23'" lmhprogram myResumes  >test.sql
```

---

Here's an excerpt from a mysqldump script that works for us...

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u username -ppassword --insert-ignore --single-transaction \
    --quick --tz-utc --no-create-db --skip-add-drop-table \
    --where="timestamp_ >= '2015-05-22' AND timestamp_ < '2015-05-23'" \
    dbname table_name | gzip -c >test.sql.gz
```

Comment: I use this script in my php file with the command exec. Maybe, it's not compatible ?